# How to preform relative import in python of package with submodules in a specific case

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, jupyter

I am having a difficult time importing my modules outside of the local folder of the package.

My folder hierarchy looks something like this:

```
root
   |- version 1.0
                |- package_name
                              |- sub_module_1
                                            |- __init__.py
                                            |- python_file.py
                              |- sub_module_2
                                            |- __init__.py
                                            |- python_file.py
                              |- __init__.py
                 |- notebook.ipynb
   |- version 2.0
                |- package_name
                              |- sub_module_1
                                            |- __init__.py
                                            |- python_file.py
                              |- sub_module_2
                                            |- __init__.py
                                            |- python_file.py
                              |- __init__.py
                 |- notebook.ipynb
   |- notebook_out.ipynb
```

If I run 'import package_name' inside 'notebook.ipynb', then everything is imported correctly. But, I want to be able to import each version separately within 'notebook_out.ipynb'. I want to be able to write something like 'import version 1.0.package_name as package_name'. The problem is caused by the fact that the '**init**.py' file of the package is looking something like this,

```
import package_name.sub_module_1
import package_name.sub_module_2
```

so when importing the package outside its local folder, the init file can not find the sub-modules. Maybe there is a walk-around, adding the paths of the local folder to PATH. I could not make it happen.